# Adding a target number into a particular position in a JavaScript Array

Tags: javascript, node.js, algorithm

I'm to create a function that returns the index of a target within a sorted numbers array if the target is found and return the index where it would be if it were inserted in order (if the target is not found).

So far, in my code, I can only return the index of a target if found but couldn't add the target to its position and return the index. My code below.

```js
function searchIndex(numbers, target) {
    let index = numbers.findIndex(x => x === target)
    if(index !== -1){
        console.log(index)
    }
}

searchIndex([1,2,3,4,5], 4)
searchIndex([3,4], 1) // to return 0
searchIndex([[8, 10, 14, 26], 25]) // to return 3
```

Comment: Search for an element that's `>= target`. The index will be the index that the new element should be in.

Answer (score 1):

If the array is sorted, then for larger arrays a binary search is the more efficient way to search the target (or its future insertion index):

```js
function searchIndex(numbers, target) {
    let low = 0, high = numbers.length;
    while (low < high) {
        let mid = (low + high) >> 1; // integer division by 2
        if      (target < numbers[mid]) high = mid;
        else if (target > numbers[mid]) low = mid + 1;
        else return mid; // found
    }
    return low; // not found
}

console.log(searchIndex([1,2,3,4,5], 4)); // 3
console.log(searchIndex([3,4], 1)); // 0
console.log(searchIndex([8, 10, 14, 26], 25)); // 3
console.log(searchIndex([1,2,3,4,5], 6)); // 5
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function searchIndex(numbers, target) {
    if(numbers.includes(target)){
        return numbers.indexOf(target)
    }else{
        numbers.push(target)
        numbers.sort((a,b)=> Number(a)-Number(b))
        return numbers.indexOf(target)
    }
}

console.log(searchIndex([1,2,3,4,5], 4))
console.log(searchIndex([3,4], 1)) // to return 0
console.log(searchIndex([8, 10, 14, 26], 25)) // to return 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Search for the first element that's `>= target`. If the target is in the array it will return its index. If not, it will return the index of the element that it should be before.

If it returns `-1`, it should be added at the end of the array, so return the array length.

```js
function searchIndex(numbers, target) {
  let index = numbers.findIndex(x => x >= target)
  if (index !== -1) {
    console.log(index);
  } else {
    console.log(numbers.length);
  }
}

searchIndex([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 4)
searchIndex([3, 4], 1) // to return 0
searchIndex([8, 10, 14, 26], 25) // to return 3
searchIndex([1, 2, 3, 4], 5) // to return 4
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function searchIndex(numbers, target) {
    let index = numbers.findIndex(x => x === target)
    if(index === -1){
    index = numbers.indexOf(numbers.filter(item => item > target)[0]);
    }
    console.log(index)
}

searchIndex([1,2,3,4,5], 4);
searchIndex([3,4], 1);// to return 0
searchIndex([8, 10, 14, 26], 25); // to return 3
```